# Camel from direct read file and process

Tags: apache-camel

I have a couple parallel routes in camel. One is reading sql data. One is reading a file on disk and then comparing to the prior sql data. I need to run route one, and based on if anything is imported, run route 2.

```
fromF("quartz2://mio/%s?cron={{route_1_cron}}", order).
        log("Running data import...").

        to("sql:{{sql_select}}").
            choice().
                when(body().isNull()).
                    stop().

                when(body().isNotNull()).
                bean(Utility.class,"incomingSqlData").
                choice().when(header("status").isEqualTo(true).
                to("direct:start").stop();
```

So far I am good. Now on the second route how do I start with from(direct:start) and then read the file from it's directory? Since I cannot have from(direct).from("file:..), since that would create two from routes.
And using from("direct:start").to("file:...") will try to write to the file.

Tl:dr: How should I start a route with direct and then **read** a file?

Comment: Take a look at content enricher and/or pollEnrich: http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @noMad17 comment, you can use a content enricher. So, your `from("direct:start")` route can look something like:

```
from("direct:start")
  .pollEnrich("file:...", new MyAggregationStrategy())
  ....
```

This will prompt your route to **read** a file.

Note that `AggregationStrategy`"is used to combine the original exchange and the resource exchange" and is optional. If not provided, then the body of resource exchange (i.e. the exchange resulting from reading the file) will overwrite the original exchange.